# PyQt: How to create custom combined titlebar and menubar

Tags: python, pyqt, menubar, titlebar

I'd like to set the menu and title in one  bar, but have no idea that how to layout the menu bar and title bar (or my own title bar).

```py
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- 

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
import sys

qss = ""

class UI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setui()  
    def setui(self):
        #----------main-window----------------------
        self.setGeometry(0,0,1366,768) #x,y,w,h
        self.setWindowTitle('hello world')
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        #----------menu-bar---------------------
        #--------file-menu-----
        self.menu_file=self.menuBar().addMenu('file')
        self.menu_file_open=self.menu_file.addAction('open')
        self.menu_file_save=self.menu_file.addAction('save')
        self.menu_file_saveas=self.menu_file.addAction('save as...')
        self.menu_file_quit=self.menu_file.addAction('exit')
        #-----------experient-menu----------
        self.menu_work=self.menuBar().addMenu('work')
        #-------------analysis-menu---------
        self.menu_analysis=self.menuBar().addMenu('analysis')
        #------------edit-menu--------------
        self.menu_edit=self.menuBar().addMenu('edit')
        #------------window-menu--------------
        self.menu_window=self.menuBar().addMenu('window')
        #------------help---menu--------------
        self.menu_help=self.menuBar().addMenu('help')
        #-------------set---qss----------------------
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)
        #-------functions--connect-------------------
        self.menu_file_quit.triggered.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)
        self.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = UI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expect a bar include icon, menus, title and the three buttons, just like the menu bar of vscode.

[image: the menu bar of vscode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QPoint, Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout,
                             QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QWidget, QAction,
                             QLabel, QSizeGrip, QMenuBar, qApp)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class TitleBar(QWidget):
    height = 35
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.menu_bar = QMenuBar()
        self.menu_bar.setStyleSheet("""
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #23272A;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 4px; 
        """)  
        self.menu_file = self.menu_bar.addMenu('file')
        self.menu_file_open=self.menu_file.addAction('open')
        self.menu_file_save=self.menu_file.addAction('save')
        self.menu_file_saveas=self.menu_file.addAction('save as...')
        self.menu_file_quit=self.menu_file.addAction('exit')
        self.menu_file_quit.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        self.menu_work=self.menu_bar.addMenu('work')
        self.menu_analysis=self.menu_bar.addMenu('analysis')
        self.menu_edit=self.menu_bar.addMenu('edit')
        self.menu_window=self.menu_bar.addMenu('window')
        self.menu_help=self.menu_bar.addMenu('help')

        self.layout.addWidget(self.menu_bar) 

        self.title = QLabel("Hello World!")
        self.title.setFixedHeight(self.height)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.title.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;  /* 23272a   #f00*/
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: blue;
            padding-left: 170px;
        """)

        self.closeButton = QPushButton(' ')                            
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_close)
        self.closeButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #DC143C;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
            font-family: "Webdings";
            qproperty-text: "r";
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.maxButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.maxButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_maximize)
        self.maxButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #32CD32;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
            font-family: "Webdings";
            qproperty-text: "1";
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.hideButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.hideButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_hide)
        self.hideButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #FFFF00;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
            font-family: "Webdings";
            qproperty-text: "0";
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.layout.addWidget(self.hideButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.maxButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False
        self.maximaze = False

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(TitleBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.parent.move(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement))
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False

    def on_click_close(self):
        sys.exit()

    def on_click_maximize(self):
        self.maximaze = not self.maximaze
        if self.maximaze:    self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowNoState)
        if not self.maximaze:
            self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

    def on_click_hide(self):
        self.parent.showMinimized()


class StatusBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StatusBar, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.showMessage("showMessage: Hello world!")

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Status bar...")
        self.label.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            color: white;
        """)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def showMessage(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(800, 400)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)        
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2c2f33;")
        self.setWindowTitle('Code Maker')

        self.title_bar = TitleBar(self) 
        self.status_bar = StatusBar(self)

        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title_bar)
        self.layout.addStretch(1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.status_bar)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)                               
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: There's a problem with your example: you're setting the title width based on the parent (which is not a good thing to do): if the "MainWindow" has no fixed size, you'll get resizing issues, most importantly recursive resizeEvents.

Comment: @musicamante  Have you tried my example and you have problems?
If you have a better answer to a question, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @SNick yes, I have tried it, that's the reason of my comment. I've proposed a different solution, but it's much more complex, and I think your solution is really fine, the only problem is the resizing: assuming people usually need to resize their windows, setting a fixed size should not be mandatory, and as soon as I removed it, I faced the infinite resizeEvent issue.

Comment: PS: There's no need for a custom QWidget for the status bar, you can use a standard QStatusBar and add it to the layout.

Comment: I didn't have the opportunity to dig deeper into your code yet, but I think I'd like to suggest you to use a plain QWidget for the title bar, with a bare minimal width (so that at least part of the title will always be visible and making it always usable for window movements), then use QFontMetrics.elideText to paint the windowTitle by hand (being careful about the `windowModified` property). This would solve the recursive resizeEvent problem, while preventing the need for setting a fixed size, keeping the interface usable and, most importantly, a code much simpler and readable than mine.

Answer (score 8):

While the answer provided by @SNick is fine, I'd like to add my own proposal.
It is a bit more complex, but has some features his solution is missing and that are quite important in my opinion.

1. it actually uses a QMainWindow;
2. it can be used with ui files created in Designer. I only tried using `uic.loadUi`, but I think it could work with files created with `pyuic` too;
3. since it can use ui files, you can create the menu directly in designer;
4. being a QMainWindow, the statusBar is an *actual* QStatusBar;
5. supports the current system theme style and colors;
6. under Windows, it supports the window system menu;
7. has no size contraints, as the menu and title resize themselves according to the available space

That said, it's not perfect. So far, the only drawback I found is that it doesn't support toolbars and dockwidgets in the top area; I *think* it could be done, but it would be a bit more complicated.

The trick is to create a QMenuBar (or use the one set in Designer) that is *not* a native one, which is very important for MacOS, and add a top margin to the central widget, then use an internal [QStyleOptionTitleBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptiontitlebar.html) to compute its size and draw its contents.

Be aware that whenever you want to add menubar items/menu, set other properties, or manually set a central widget, you must ensure that you do that *after* the `*** END OF SETUP ***` comment.

```
import sys
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    import win32gui
    import win32con
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# a "fake" button class that we need for hover and click events
class HiddenButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    hover = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(HiddenButton, self).__init__(parent)
        # prevent any painting to keep this button "invisible" while
        # still reacting to its events
        self.setUpdatesEnabled(False)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit()


class SpecialTitleWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    __watchedActions = (
        QtCore.QEvent.ActionAdded, 
        QtCore.QEvent.ActionChanged, 
        QtCore.QEvent.ActionRemoved
    )
    titleOpt = None
    __menuBar = None
    __titleBarMousePos = None
    __sysMenuLock = False
    __topMargin = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).__init__()
        self.widgetHelpers = []
#        uic.loadUi('titlebar.ui', self)
        # enable the system menu
        self.setWindowFlags(
            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
        )
        # set the WindowActive to ensure that the title bar is painted as active
        self.setWindowState(self.windowState() | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)

        # create a StyleOption that we need for painting and computing sizes
        self.titleOpt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTitleBar()
        self.titleOpt.initFrom(self)
        self.titleOpt.titleBarFlags = (
            QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsOwnDC |
            QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint |
            QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowMinMaxButtonsHint | 
            QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint
            )
        self.titleOpt.state |= (QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active | 
            QtWidgets.QStyle.State_HasFocus)
        self.titleOpt.titleBarState = (int(self.windowState()) | 
            int(QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active))

        # create "fake" buttons
        self.systemButton = HiddenButton(self)
        self.systemButton.pressed.connect(self.showSystemMenu)
        self.minimizeButton = HiddenButton(self)
        self.minimizeButton.hover.connect(self.checkHoverStates)
        self.minimizeButton.clicked.connect(self.minimize)
        self.maximizeButton = HiddenButton(self)
        self.maximizeButton.hover.connect(self.checkHoverStates)
        self.maximizeButton.clicked.connect(self.maximize)
        self.closeButton = HiddenButton(self)
        self.closeButton.hover.connect(self.checkHoverStates)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.ctrlButtons = {
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarMinButton: self.minimizeButton, 
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarMaxButton: self.maximizeButton, 
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarNormalButton: self.maximizeButton, 
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarCloseButton: self.closeButton, 
        }

        self.widgetHelpers.extend([self.minimizeButton, self.maximizeButton, self.closeButton])

        self.resetTitleHeight()

        # *** END OF SETUP ***

        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction('Open')
        fileMenu.addAction('Save')
        workMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Work')
        workMenu.addAction('Work something')
        analysisMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Analysis')
        analysisMenu.addAction('Analize action')

        # just call the statusBar to create one, we use it for resizing purposes
        self.statusBar()

    def resetTitleHeight(self):
        # minimum height for the menu can change everytime an action is added,
        # removed or modified; let's update it accordingly
        if not self.titleOpt:
            return
        # set the minimum height of the titlebar
        self.titleHeight = max(
            self.style().pixelMetric(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_TitleBarHeight, self.titleOpt, self), 
            self.menuBar().sizeHint().height()
            )
        self.titleOpt.rect.setHeight(self.titleHeight)
        self.menuBar().setMaximumHeight(self.titleHeight)
        if self.minimumHeight() < self.titleHeight:
            self.setMinimumHeight(self.titleHeight)

    def checkHoverStates(self):
        if not self.titleOpt:
            return
        # update the window buttons when hovering
        pos = self.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        for ctrl, btn in self.ctrlButtons.items():
            rect = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar, 
                self.titleOpt, ctrl, self)
            # since the maximize button can become a "restore", ensure that it
            # actually exists according to the current state, if the rect
            # has an actual size
            if rect and pos in rect:
                self.titleOpt.activeSubControls = ctrl
                self.titleOpt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver
                break
        else:
            # no hover
            self.titleOpt.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver
            self.titleOpt.activeSubControls = QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_None
        self.titleOpt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active
        self.update()

    def showSystemMenu(self, pos=None):
        # show the system menu on windows
        if sys.platform != 'win32':
            return
        if self.__sysMenuLock:
            self.__sysMenuLock = False
            return
        winId = int(self.effectiveWinId())
        sysMenu = win32gui.GetSystemMenu(winId, False)
        if pos is None:
            pos = self.systemButton.mapToGlobal(self.systemButton.rect().bottomLeft())
            self.__sysMenuLock = True
        cmd = win32gui.TrackPopupMenu(sysMenu, 
            win32gui.TPM_LEFTALIGN | win32gui.TPM_TOPALIGN | win32gui.TPM_RETURNCMD, 
            pos.x(), pos.y(), 0, winId, None)
        win32gui.PostMessage(winId, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, cmd, 0)
        # restore the menu lock to hide it when clicking the system menu icon
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: setattr(self, '__sysMenuLock', False))

    def actualWindowTitle(self):
        # window title can show "*" for modified windows
        title = self.windowTitle()
        if title:
            title = title.replace('[*]', '*' if self.isWindowModified() else '')
        return title

    def updateTitleBar(self):
        # compute again sizes when resizing or changing window title
        menuWidth = self.menuBar().sizeHint().width()
        availableRect = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar, 
            self.titleOpt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarLabel, self)
        left = availableRect.left()
        if self.menuBar().sizeHint().height() < self.titleHeight:
            top = (self.titleHeight - self.menuBar().sizeHint().height()) // 2
            height = self.menuBar().sizeHint().height()
        else:
            top = 0
            height = self.titleHeight
        title = self.actualWindowTitle()
        titleWidth = self.fontMetrics().width(title)
        if not title and menuWidth > availableRect.width():
            # resize the menubar to its maximum, but without hiding the buttons
            width = availableRect.width()
        elif menuWidth + titleWidth > availableRect.width():
            # if the menubar and title require more than the available space, 
            # divide it equally, giving precedence to the window title space,
            # since it is also necessary for window movement
            width = availableRect.width() // 2
            if menuWidth > titleWidth:
                width = max(left, min(availableRect.width() - titleWidth, width))
            # keep a minimum size for the menu arrow
            if availableRect.width() - width < left:
                width = left
            extButton = self.menuBar().findChild(QtWidgets.QToolButton, 'qt_menubar_ext_button')
            if self.isVisible() and extButton:
                # if the "extButton" is visible (meaning that some item 
                # is hidden due to the menubar cannot be completely shown)
                # resize to the last visible item + extButton, so that
                # there's as much space available for the title
                minWidth = extButton.width()
                menuBar = self.menuBar()
                spacing = self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_MenuBarItemSpacing)
                for i, action in enumerate(menuBar.actions()):
                    actionWidth = menuBar.actionGeometry(action).width()
                    if minWidth + actionWidth > width:
                        width = minWidth
                        break
                    minWidth += actionWidth + spacing
        else:
            width = menuWidth
        self.menuBar().setGeometry(left, top, width, height)

        # ensure that our internal widget are always on top
        for w in self.widgetHelpers:
            w.raise_()
        self.update()

    # helper function to avoid "ugly" colors on menubar items
    def __setMenuBar(self, menuBar):
        if self.__menuBar:
            if self.__menuBar in self.widgetHelpers:
                self.widgetHelpers.remove(self.__menuBar)
            self.__menuBar.removeEventFilter(self)
        self.__menuBar = menuBar
        self.widgetHelpers.append(menuBar)
        self.__menuBar.installEventFilter(self)
        self.__menuBar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
        self.__menuBar.setStyleSheet('''
            QMenuBar {
                background-color: transparent;
            }
            QMenuBar::item {
                background-color: transparent;
            }
            QMenuBar::item:selected {
                background-color: palette(button);
            }
        ''')

    def setMenuBar(self, menuBar):
        self.__setMenuBar(menuBar)

    def menuBar(self):
        # QMainWindow.menuBar() returns a new blank menu bar if none exists
        if not self.__menuBar:
            self.__setMenuBar(QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self))
        return self.__menuBar

    def setCentralWidget(self, widget):
        if self.centralWidget():
            self.centralWidget().removeEventFilter(self)
        # store the top content margin, we need it later
        l, self.__topMargin, r, b = widget.getContentsMargins()
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).setCentralWidget(widget)
        # since the central widget always uses all the available space and can
        # capture mouse events, install an event filter to catch them and
        # allow us to grab them
        widget.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.centralWidget():
            # do not propagate mouse press events to the centralWidget!
            if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and 
                event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and 
                event.y() <= self.titleHeight):
                    self.__titleBarMousePos = event.pos()
                    event.accept()
                    return True
        elif source == self.__menuBar and event.type() in self.__watchedActions:
            self.resetTitleHeight()
        return super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def minimize(self):
        self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized)

    def maximize(self):
        if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized:
            self.setWindowState(
                self.windowState() & (~QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive))
        else:
            self.setWindowState(
                self.windowState() | QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
        # whenever a window is resized, its button states have to be checked again
        self.checkHoverStates()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        if event.pos() not in self.menuBar().geometry():
            self.showSystemMenu(event.globalPos())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.centralWidget() and (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and 
            event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and event.y() <= self.titleHeight):
                self.__titleBarMousePos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and self.__titleBarMousePos:
            # move the window
            self.move(self.pos() + event.pos() - self.__titleBarMousePos)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.maximize()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.__titleBarMousePos = None

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        # change the appearance of the titlebar according to the window state
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ActivationChange:
            if self.isActiveWindow():
                self.titleOpt.titleBarState = (
                    int(self.windowState()) | int(QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active))
                self.titleOpt.palette.setCurrentColorGroup(QtGui.QPalette.Active)
            else:
                self.titleOpt.titleBarState = 0
                self.titleOpt.palette.setCurrentColorGroup(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive)
            self.update()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            self.checkHoverStates()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowTitleChange:
            if self.titleOpt:
                self.updateTitleBar()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not event.spontaneous():
            # update the titlebar as soon as it's shown, to ensure that
            # most of the title text is visible
            self.updateTitleBar()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)
        # update the centralWidget contents margins, adding the titlebar height
        # to the top margin found before
        if (self.centralWidget() and 
            self.centralWidget().getContentsMargins()[1] + self.__topMargin != self.titleHeight):
                l, t, r, b = self.centralWidget().getContentsMargins()
                self.centralWidget().setContentsMargins(
                    l, self.titleHeight + self.__topMargin, r, b)
        # resize the width of the titlebar option, and move its buttons
        self.titleOpt.rect.setWidth(self.width())
        for ctrl, btn in self.ctrlButtons.items():
            rect = self.style().subControlRect(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar, self.titleOpt, ctrl, self)
            if rect:
                btn.setGeometry(rect)
        sysRect = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar, 
            self.titleOpt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarSysMenu, self)
        if sysRect:
            self.systemButton.setGeometry(sysRect)
        self.titleOpt.titleBarState = int(self.windowState())
        if self.isActiveWindow():
            self.titleOpt.titleBarState |= int(QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active)
        self.updateTitleBar()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawComplexControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar, self.titleOpt, qp, self)
        titleRect = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar, 
            self.titleOpt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarLabel, self)
        icon = self.windowIcon()
        if not icon.isNull():
            iconRect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, titleRect.left(), self.titleHeight)
            qp.drawPixmap(iconRect, icon.pixmap(iconRect.size()))
        title = self.actualWindowTitle()
        titleRect.setLeft(self.menuBar().geometry().right())
        if title:
            # move left of the rectangle available for the title to the right of
            # the menubar; if the title is bigger than the available space, elide it
            elided = self.fontMetrics().elidedText(
                title, QtCore.Qt.ElideRight, titleRect.width() - 2)
            qp.drawText(titleRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, elided)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SpecialTitleWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('My window')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I liked your option. If you add the ability to move the window, it will be even more beautiful :)

Comment: I did forgot to specify support in case no QWidget was set (in my tests I used an `ui` file). Now it should work fine in both cases. I've found an issue for Linux, though, but I'm not sure it's a bug or not (and if it has been fixed, since I'm using an old version of Qt5). As soon as I can find a fix/explanation for it, I'll update the answer again.

Comment: @SNick: Got it! The problem was that in my tests I added items to the menubar *after* setting the `titleHeight`: in the former code the menuBar was empty when setting it, using a too small value (titleBar height), preventing the correct display of items: on some platform/style the titleBar height hint is smaller than standard menu item ones, and since the menu was empty there was no higher value for `max()`. I modified its logic, with the most important part being updating the titleHeight everytime a QAction is changed or added to/removed from the menuBar. Btw: I'm glad you liked it, thanks :)

Comment: Works great, from me `+`, but for a beginner it is very difficult.

Comment: @SNick: Yes, I agree, it's not for the "faint hearted coder", that's why I think that your answer is more fitting for this answer, at least by the OP experience. But I thought that it was an interesting question worth the effort, and it might be useful for anybody in the future. Including us :-)

Comment: @musicamante, your solution is cool and worthy of being studied. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I did a few patches so that the code provided by @musicamante can work on PySide6, but I found that when moving the window, it's shaking. When I looked at the mouseMoveEvent and read qt's document about `event.pos()` in `QMouseEvent`, which says:

> If you move the widget as a result of the mouse event, use the global position returned by `globalPos()` to avoid a shaking motion.

So I replaced

```py
self.move(self.pos() + event.pos() - self.__titleBarMousePos)
```

with

```py
self.move(event.globalPos() - self.__titleBarMousePos)
```

in `mouseMoveEvent()`

Here is the PySide6 version:

```py
import sys
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    import win32gui
    import win32con
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# a "fake" button class that we need for hover and click events
class HiddenButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    hover = QtCore.Signal()
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(HiddenButton, self).__init__(parent)
        # prevent any painting to keep this button "invisible" while
        # still reacting to its events
        self.setUpdatesEnabled(False)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit()


class SpecialTitleWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    __watchedActions = (
        QtCore.QEvent.ActionAdded,
        QtCore.QEvent.ActionChanged,
        QtCore.QEvent.ActionRemoved
    )
    titleOpt = None
    __menuBar = None
    __titleBarMousePos = None
    __sysMenuLock = False
    __topMargin = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).__init__()
        self.widgetHelpers = []
#        uic.loadUi('titlebar.ui', self)
        # enable the system menu
        self.setWindowFlags(
            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
        )
        # set the WindowActive to ensure that the title bar is painted as active
        self.setWindowState(self.windowState() | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)

        # create a StyleOption that we need for painting and computing sizes
        self.titleOpt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTitleBar()
        self.titleOpt.initFrom(self)
        self.titleOpt.titleBarFlags = (
            QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsOwnDC |
            QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint |
            QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowMinMaxButtonsHint |
            QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint
            )
        self.titleOpt.state |= (QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active |
            QtWidgets.QStyle.State_HasFocus)
        self.titleOpt.titleBarState = (int(self.windowState()) |
            int(QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active))

        # create "fake" buttons
        self.systemButton = HiddenButton(self)
        self.systemButton.pressed.connect(self.showSystemMenu)
        self.minimizeButton = HiddenButton(self)
        self.minimizeButton.hover.connect(self.checkHoverStates)
        self.minimizeButton.clicked.connect(self.minimize)
        self.maximizeButton = HiddenButton(self)
        self.maximizeButton.hover.connect(self.checkHoverStates)
        self.maximizeButton.clicked.connect(self.maximize)
        self.closeButton = HiddenButton(self)
        self.closeButton.hover.connect(self.checkHoverStates)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.ctrlButtons = {
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarMinButton: self.minimizeButton,
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarMaxButton: self.maximizeButton,
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarNormalButton: self.maximizeButton,
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarCloseButton: self.closeButton,
        }

        self.widgetHelpers.extend([self.minimizeButton, self.maximizeButton, self.closeButton])

        self.resetTitleHeight()

        # *** END OF SETUP ***

        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction('Open')
        fileMenu.addAction('Save')
        workMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Work')
        workMenu.addAction('Work something')
        analysisMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Analysis')
        analysisMenu.addAction('Analize action')

        # just call the statusBar to create one, we use it for resizing purposes
        self.statusBar()
        self.resize(400, 250)

    def resetTitleHeight(self):
        # minimum height for the menu can change everytime an action is added,
        # removed or modified; let's update it accordingly
        if not self.titleOpt:
            return
        # set the minimum height of the titlebar
        self.titleHeight = max(
            self.style().pixelMetric(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_TitleBarHeight, self.titleOpt, self),
            self.menuBar().sizeHint().height()
            )
        self.titleOpt.rect.setHeight(self.titleHeight)
        self.menuBar().setMaximumHeight(self.titleHeight)
        if self.minimumHeight() < self.titleHeight:
            self.setMinimumHeight(self.titleHeight)

    def checkHoverStates(self):
        if not self.titleOpt:
            return
        # update the window buttons when hovering
        pos = self.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        for ctrl, btn in self.ctrlButtons.items():
            rect = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar,
                self.titleOpt, ctrl, self)
            # since the maximize button can become a "restore", ensure that it
            # actually exists according to the current state, if the rect
            # has an actual size
            if rect and rect.contains(pos):
                self.titleOpt.activeSubControls = ctrl
                self.titleOpt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver
                break
        else:
            # no hover
            self.titleOpt.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver
            self.titleOpt.activeSubControls = QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_None
        self.titleOpt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active
        self.update()

    def showSystemMenu(self, pos=None):
        # show the system menu on windows
        if sys.platform != 'win32':
            return
        if self.__sysMenuLock:
            self.__sysMenuLock = False
            return
        winId = int(self.effectiveWinId())
        sysMenu = win32gui.GetSystemMenu(winId, False)
        if pos is None:
            pos = self.systemButton.mapToGlobal(self.systemButton.rect().bottomLeft())
            self.__sysMenuLock = True
        cmd = win32gui.TrackPopupMenu(sysMenu,
            win32gui.TPM_LEFTALIGN | win32gui.TPM_TOPALIGN | win32gui.TPM_RETURNCMD,
            pos.x(), pos.y(), 0, winId, None)
        win32gui.PostMessage(winId, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, cmd, 0)
        # restore the menu lock to hide it when clicking the system menu icon
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: setattr(self, '__sysMenuLock', False))

    def actualWindowTitle(self):
        # window title can show "*" for modified windows
        title = self.windowTitle()
        if title:
            title = title.replace('[*]', '*' if self.isWindowModified() else '')
        return title

    def updateTitleBar(self):
        # compute again sizes when resizing or changing window title
        menuWidth = self.menuBar().sizeHint().width()
        availableRect = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar,
            self.titleOpt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarLabel, self)
        left = availableRect.left()
        if self.menuBar().sizeHint().height() < self.titleHeight:
            top = (self.titleHeight - self.menuBar().sizeHint().height()) // 2
            height = self.menuBar().sizeHint().height()
        else:
            top = 0
            height = self.titleHeight
        title = self.actualWindowTitle()
        titleWidth = self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(title).width()
        if not title and menuWidth > availableRect.width():
            # resize the menubar to its maximum, but without hiding the buttons
            width = availableRect.width()
        elif menuWidth + titleWidth > availableRect.width():
            # if the menubar and title require more than the available space,
            # divide it equally, giving precedence to the window title space,
            # since it is also necessary for window movement
            width = availableRect.width() // 2
            if menuWidth > titleWidth:
                width = max(left, min(availableRect.width() - titleWidth, width))
            # keep a minimum size for the menu arrow
            if availableRect.width() - width < left:
                width = left
            extButton = self.menuBar().findChild(QtWidgets.QToolButton, 'qt_menubar_ext_button')
            if self.isVisible() and extButton:
                # if the "extButton" is visible (meaning that some item
                # is hidden due to the menubar cannot be completely shown)
                # resize to the last visible item + extButton, so that
                # there's as much space available for the title
                minWidth = extButton.width()
                menuBar = self.menuBar()
                spacing = self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_MenuBarItemSpacing)
                for i, action in enumerate(menuBar.actions()):
                    actionWidth = menuBar.actionGeometry(action).width()
                    if minWidth + actionWidth > width:
                        width = minWidth
                        break
                    minWidth += actionWidth + spacing
        else:
            width = menuWidth
        self.menuBar().setGeometry(left, top, width, height)

        # ensure that our internal widget are always on top
        for w in self.widgetHelpers:
            w.raise_()
        self.update()

    # helper function to avoid "ugly" colors on menubar items
    def __setMenuBar(self, menuBar):
        if self.__menuBar:
            if self.__menuBar in self.widgetHelpers:
                self.widgetHelpers.remove(self.__menuBar)
            self.__menuBar.removeEventFilter(self)
        self.__menuBar = menuBar
        self.widgetHelpers.append(menuBar)
        self.__menuBar.installEventFilter(self)
        self.__menuBar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
        self.__menuBar.setStyleSheet('''
            QMenuBar {
                background-color: transparent;
            }
            QMenuBar::item {
                background-color: transparent;
            }
            QMenuBar::item:selected {
                background-color: palette(button);
            }
        ''')

    def setMenuBar(self, menuBar):
        self.__setMenuBar(menuBar)

    def menuBar(self):
        # QMainWindow.menuBar() returns a new blank menu bar if none exists
        if not self.__menuBar:
            self.__setMenuBar(QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self))
        return self.__menuBar

    def setCentralWidget(self, widget):
        if self.centralWidget():
            self.centralWidget().removeEventFilter(self)
        # store the top content margin, we need it later
        l, self.__topMargin, r, b = widget.contentsMargins()
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).setCentralWidget(widget)
        # since the central widget always uses all the available space and can
        # capture mouse events, install an event filter to catch them and
        # allow us to grab them
        widget.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.centralWidget():
            # do not propagate mouse press events to the centralWidget!
            if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and
                event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and
                event.y() <= self.titleHeight):
                    self.__titleBarMousePos = event.pos()
                    event.accept()
                    return True
        elif source == self.__menuBar and event.type() in self.__watchedActions:
            self.resetTitleHeight()
        return super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def minimize(self):
        self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized)

    def maximize(self):
        if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized:
            self.setWindowState(
                self.windowState() & (~QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive))
        else:
            self.setWindowState(
                self.windowState() | QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
        # whenever a window is resized, its button states have to be checked again
        self.checkHoverStates()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        if not self.menuBar().geometry().contains(event.pos()):
            self.showSystemMenu(event.globalPos())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.centralWidget() and (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and
            event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and event.position().y() <= self.titleHeight):
                self.__titleBarMousePos = event.position()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and self.__titleBarMousePos:
            # move the window
            self.move((event.globalPosition() - self.__titleBarMousePos).toPoint())

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.maximize()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.__titleBarMousePos = None

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        # change the appearance of the titlebar according to the window state
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ActivationChange:
            if self.isActiveWindow():
                self.titleOpt.titleBarState = (
                    int(self.windowState()) | int(QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active))
                self.titleOpt.palette.setCurrentColorGroup(QtGui.QPalette.Active)
            else:
                self.titleOpt.titleBarState = 0
                self.titleOpt.palette.setCurrentColorGroup(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive)
            self.update()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            self.checkHoverStates()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowTitleChange:
            if self.titleOpt:
                self.updateTitleBar()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not event.spontaneous():
            # update the titlebar as soon as it's shown, to ensure that
            # most of the title text is visible
            self.updateTitleBar()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(SpecialTitleWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)
        # update the centralWidget contents margins, adding the titlebar height
        # to the top margin found before
        if (self.centralWidget() and
            self.centralWidget().getContentsMargins()[1] + self.__topMargin != self.titleHeight):
                l, t, r, b = self.centralWidget().getContentsMargins()
                self.centralWidget().setContentsMargins(
                    l, self.titleHeight + self.__topMargin, r, b)
        # resize the width of the titlebar option, and move its buttons
        self.titleOpt.rect.setWidth(self.width())
        for ctrl, btn in self.ctrlButtons.items():
            rect = self.style().subControlRect(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar, self.titleOpt, ctrl, self)
            if rect:
                btn.setGeometry(rect)
        sysRect = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar,
            self.titleOpt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarSysMenu, self)
        if sysRect:
            self.systemButton.setGeometry(sysRect)
        self.titleOpt.titleBarState = int(self.windowState())
        if self.isActiveWindow():
            self.titleOpt.titleBarState |= int(QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Active)
        self.updateTitleBar()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawComplexControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar, self.titleOpt, qp, self)
        titleRect = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar,
            self.titleOpt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_TitleBarLabel, self)
        icon = self.windowIcon()
        if not icon.isNull():
            iconRect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, titleRect.left(), self.titleHeight)
            qp.drawPixmap(iconRect, icon.pixmap(iconRect.size()))
        title = self.actualWindowTitle()
        titleRect.setLeft(self.menuBar().geometry().right())
        if title:
            # move left of the rectangle available for the title to the right of
            # the menubar; if the title is bigger than the available space, elide it
            elided = self.fontMetrics().elidedText(
                title, QtCore.Qt.ElideRight, titleRect.width() - 2)
            qp.drawText(titleRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, elided)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SpecialTitleWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('My window')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```